# Prevent electric-indent-mode from reindenting the current line on RET

Tags: spacemacs, python, indentation, electric-indent

I am using the Spacemacs configuration files.

When I am typing code, electric-indent-mode reindents the current line whenever I press enter. This often causes the indentation to be incorrect when working in languages like Python or Haskell.

[Here is an example of the problem](https://i.imgur.com/UP3y4Tp.gifv)

How can I prevent this re-indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those major modes like python-mode and haskell-mode set (or should set) `electric-indent-inhibit`.